# Amazon RDS Enhanced Monitoring

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I have RDS DB with low number of connections on it (usually something around 30 connections), but it shows high CPU load all the time (about 25%). The DB Family (r3.2xlarge) .
As shown in the screenshot below of enhanced monitoring, it shows some processes with high CPU and Memory utilization. what does the numbers that i have marked in rectangles mean? I thought they are the threads' IDs of Queries, but in show processlist, i can't see those numbers!
So briefly:

1. What does those numbers (in rectangle) mean?
2. is there anyway to know which query is taking the top utilization of CPU and memory (in realtime, not via slow log)?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> What does those numbers (in rectangle) mean?

They are just process/thread IDs. Don't mean anything.

> is there anyway to know which query is taking the top utilization of CPU and memory (in realtime, not via slow log)?

Since you're using MySQL flavor of RDS, connect to your instance with any MySQL client and use `SHOW PROCESSLIST;` or `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;` commands to see the list of running queries.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/show-processlist.html

Comment: Re: They are just process/thread IDs. Don't mean anything.>>> They are not, i thought the same... 
Re show processlist, i am aware of it, and sometimes all of the processes are in "Sleep" Command, which means almost nothing running,, but still the cpu load is about 25%

Comment: Possible cause: you have an expensive replication going.

Comment: @Alaa these are process/thead IDs from the OS, not client thread IDs from the processlist.  There are other possible causes.  InnoDB, for example, will have a background thread that manages [change buffering](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-insert-buffering.html) -- changes made by insert/update queries are committed to disk immediately, are safely stored, and immediately accessible, but they can be stored in a holding area and merged unto the actual tablespaces in the background, later.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot , thanks for your reply.... does it mean that they are out of user's control? if so, what is the added value from it (from point of view of Amazon)